# C string - getting length with custom function

Tags: c, string, function, parameters, char

I'm working on some functions concerning strings but I'm still missing something.

```
unsigned int stringLength(const char source[]) //source[] je předaný jako pointer
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(source[i] != '\0'){ //'a' je char a "a" je string resp. char array ['a', '\0']
        i++;
    }
    return i; //length
}
```

//this function works, for "abef" it outputs 4 etc. how do I use it in 
the following function though?

```
int isPalindrome(const char source[]) //array name dává pointer na první char v stringu
{
    //malloc tested[] podle stringLength vstupu?, tested+1 pro \0 znak? uvidíme
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;
    char tested[>>>PASS SOURCE LENGTH HERE<<<<]; //bude končit \0 nebo ne? je to char array nebo string?
    while(source[i] != '\0'){ //ascii hodnoty 90-65 = 25 && 122-97 = 25, 'a' = 97, 'b' = 98 (automatická konverze)
        if((source[i]-97) <= (25)){  //if je malé písmeno (97 až 122)
            tested[j] = source[i]; //přiřadit znak do kontrolování palindromu
            j++;
        }
        if((source[i]-65) <= (25)){  //if je velké písmeno (65 až 90)
            tested[j] = source[i]+32; //--> malé písmeno
            j++;
        }
        else if(source[i] == 32 || source[i] == 10 || source[i] == 9){ //whitespace
        }
        else{ //ostatní znaky ascii tabulky
            tested[j] = source[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++; //další znak ze vstupu
    }
    //tested nyní obsahuje platné znaky k testování

}
```

as putting stringLength(source) or stringLength(source[]) doesn't work.

Comment: It would help if you showed the _code that does not work_ and explain how it does not not work, and how you expect it to work.  In this case it is not clear where you might have used `stringLength()` in your failed attempt.

Comment: What compiler are you using and what options are passed? Variable-length arrays are supported in C99.

Comment: Yes thanks for answer. I need to pass the `source[]` length into the place where I wrote >>>PASS SOURCE LENGTH HERE<<<< because I need to specify the size of the char array `tested[]` which I want to make the same size as `source[]` (or +1 because of the \0 but I'll solve that later).

Comment: Why char tested[stringLength(source)] dosent work? What error do you get

Comment: In fact, using `stringLength(source)` really works....... I'm sorry for troubling you guys. I only thought it didn't work because of pythontutor giving me errors because of a typo and qtCreator marking that line red (still marking the line red though). Nevermind.